# Check in Zope if a Object / image is available / uploaded

Tags: python, zope

im using zope2.10 with python
and i would like to check if a image File is uploaded

I am in my own Product and i have a path as string like:

/Media/News/2010/image

and i want to check if it is image.gif or image.jpg

But i don't know how to check 
So it will be just a file checker.

Does the file exist in zope yes/no ready

//EDIT I'm not an a dtml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal filesystem Python code, you would use the path to traverse to to container, and then check the two IDs in the container.  E.g.:

```
container = context.unrestrictedTraverse('/media/news/2010')
item_ids = list(container.objectIds())
for image_id in ('image.jpg', 'image.gif', 'image.png'):
    if image_id in item_ids:
        return container._getOb(image_id).absolute_url()
raise ValueError('No image found')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly remember, you can use the has_key() method.

Now, depending on whether you're using dtml, python or whatever, you can do something like

```
<dtml-with Media>
  <dtml-with News>
    <dtml-with 2010>
      <dtml-if "getattr(_['2010'], 'Image').has_key('Image.gif')">
        ...
      </dtml-else>
        ...
      </dtml-if>
    </dtml-with>
  </dtml-with>
</dtml-with>
```

I didn't test the code, but I'm pretty sure the has_key() method is your solution. You can use it in dtml or in python scripts.

Comment: The Problem is that i am in a Product where i want to check the file.

But the file is in a Directory of a other Product Like:

I am here: /Prodcuts/cms/filechecker

And here is the file /Products/Media/News/2010/image(.jpg/.gif)

Comment: well, remember that getattr(_['2010'],'Image').has_key('Image.gif') is between "" in dtml. thus it is python anc can be used in scripts or whatever. With getattr you can traverse the items stored in the ZODB, and with has_key you can check if a particular id is present or not.

Comment: DTML? This also deserves a -1